# Sticky Sidebar - Stop at element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sidebar, sticky

I want to have a stick sitebar. I searched and found this code:

```
<script>
    var sidebar = $('#sidebar-content'),
        nav = $('.sidebar-content'),
        startPosition = sidebar .offset().top,
        stopPosition = $('#abspann').offset().top - nav.outerHeight();

    $(document).scroll(function () {
        //stick nav to top of page 
        var y = $(this).scrollTop()

        if (y > startPosition) {
            nav.addClass('sticky');
            if (y > stopPosition) {
                nav.css('top', stopPosition - y);
            } else {
                nav.css('top', 0);
            }
        } else {
            nav.removeClass('sticky');
        } 
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that it doesn't work... I already tried to replaced the `$` with a `jQuery` but still... doesn't work. The only reason can be the error I still get in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefinedat
>   (index):411

Currently the code is looking like this:

```
<script>
var sidebar = jQuery('#sidebar-wrap'),
    nav = jQuery('.sidebar-content'),
    startPosition = jQuery('#sidebar-wrap').offset().top,
    stopPosition = jQuery('#abspann').offset().top - nav.outerHeight();

jQuery(document).scroll(function () {
    //stick nav to top of page
    var y = jQuery(this).scrollTop()

    if (y > startPosition) {
        nav.addClass('sticky');
        if (y > stopPosition) {
            nav.css('top', stopPosition - y);
        } else {
            nav.css('top', 0);
        }
    } else {
        nav.removeClass('sticky');
    } 
});
</script>
```

If it's working, the sidebar should stop at the element `#abspann`. Just to know.

The site I'am talking about is [this](https://digital-hacks.de/vpn-verbindung-einrichten/). And the sourcecode can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ykto7uu9/1/).

How can I get this working?

Kind Regards

Comment: The Fiddle is working perfectly fine for me, in Firefox.

Comment: Yeah, in my browser also... But not on my site..

Answer (score 1):

It is because your script is loaded before loading your elements so use [$.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready) so that every element is available before using it.

```
<script src="JQUERY_LIB_URL_HERE"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(function(){
       var sidebar = jQuery('#sidebar-wrap'),
        nav = jQuery('.sidebar-content'),
        startPosition = jQuery('#sidebar-wrap').offset().top,
        stopPosition = jQuery('#abspann').offset().top - nav.outerHeight();
        jQuery(document).scroll(function () {
            //stick nav to top of page
            var y = jQuery(this).scrollTop()

            if (y > startPosition) {
                nav.addClass('sticky');
                if (y > stopPosition) {
                    nav.css('top', stopPosition - y);
                } else {
                    nav.css('top', 0);
                }
            } else {
                nav.removeClass('sticky');
            } 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Now I get `(index):409 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at (index):409` at the beginning of the function...

Comment: Before adding the code first include jquery library, then write relevant code for scroll. Or Replace `$` by `jQuery`, You can get hint from my updated answer.

Comment: Or change the `$` into a `jQuery`, in case you are using jQuery in compatibility mode. You can even put a `$` as the parameter of the function, so that you can use `$` inside the function.

Comment: ok, now it is a kind of working... can you pls check? - but why isn't the sidebar stopping at `#abpsann`?

Comment: I don't think so, anyone can help you in finding your hidden problem according to your posted code. So I think you should edit your question with a snippet/fiddle, and/or if this is new then ask another question.